# Issue with blinking screen above 4.20.17 kernel [CPU, GPU]

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, kernel, screen, cpu

My notebook with Intel i7-7700Q and Nvidia 1050Ti have real problem with blinking/pulse of the screen during the moving cursor in the system or high performance usage (ex. code compilation).

I did not notice the issue, until I felt my eyes were bleeding and going to go out from sockets.

At the beginning I thought that the problem is with screen refreshing, but after changing the kernel using Ukuu on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS over and over again I found kernel 4.20.17. This one is good for my notebook configurations and screen acts well.

Why I am asking? Sometimes I cannot continue my work after suspending laptop, due to the poor performance. I thought newer kernels will solve the issues with poor performance and blinking screen.
Will it be solved?

I tried to set conf files for nautilus or nvidia, updating the Nvidia. Noting helped. Do you encountered any similar situation?

Comment: Supported kernels for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS are 4.15 & 5.0 (via HWE) currently; kernel 4.20 is EOL & unsupported so unless you're backporting the security upgrades yourself - I'd suggest switching to a supported kernel.